# how to get the objectname from <class 'lxml.html.HtmlElement'>

Tags: python

```py
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq 
print(pq(url='https://www.bing.com')('div'))
```

if I run code in terminal, only output this

```
<div id="hp_container"><div id="bgDiv"><div id="bgImgProgLoad" data-ultra-definition-src="/th?id=OHR.AltaFloresta_...
```

```py
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq 
pq(url='https://www.bing.com')('div')
```

When I run the above code in jupyterab, I get following result

```
[<div#hp_container>, <div#bgDiv>, <div#bgImgProgLoad>, ...]
```

The selector of each div tag is automatically displayed in the result, such like **div#hp_container**,
Now I can only see them in the output in jupyterlab, I don't know what kind of attribute or method to get each selector name itself.

=================================

2021-05-15 Comment Add Picture
[image]

I mean when I enter `x`, I can see a list of selectors, I just don't know how to convert it to a list of str

Answer (score 0):

The 'selector', or rather the classes of each element are available as a `.classes` iterable on the element:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

for div in pq(url='https://www.bing.com')('div'):
    print(list(div.classes))
```

Result:

```
['hpapp']
['hp_body']
['hpl']
['img_cont']
```

Etc. (casting to string for printing)

If you simply want to display the element names and classes as JupyterLab apparently does for you:

```py
for elem in pq(url='https://www.bing.com')('div'):
    print(f'{elem.tag}#{".".join(elem.classes)}')
```

Result:

```
div#hpapp
div#hp_body
div#hpl
div#img_cont
```

Etc.

Comment: Thx a lot,  I can use code such like `pq(url='https://www.bing.com')('div.sw_sform')[0].attrib` get attr `{'id': 'sbox', 'class': 'sw_sform'}`and assembling it, but the selector already assembled in the result `[...,<div#sbox.sw_sform>,...]`, I just don't know how to get this string

Comment: The part after the `#` appears to be nothing but the classes of the element. Are you asking how to combine the element name `div` and its classes `sbox` and `sw_form` in to a string like `div#sbox.sw_form`? I.e. `f'{elem.tag}#{".".join(elem.classes)}'`?

Comment: Maybe there is a mistake in my expression, I mean I have seen the result, but I don't know how to get it directly, I edited my question and added more details in there.